# Append an index number to a variable name in bash?

Tags: bash

I am trying to loop through numbered variables but am having a hard time appending the loop index number to the base variable name. Code follows, using a 2-iteration example:

```
#ENTER TOTAL NUMBER OF RUNS HERE:
nruns=2

# START DATE/TIME              #END DATE/TIME
#*****************             ***************
#RUN 1          #RUN 2         #RUN 1              #RUN2
yr1=2008;       yr2=2008;      eyr1=2008;          eyr2=2008;
mo1=11;         mo2=12;        emo1=12;            emo2=12;
day1=30;        day2=1;        eday1=2;            eday2=3;
hr1=18;         hr2=18;        ehr1=00;            ehr2=00;
min1=00;        min2=00;       emin1=00;           emin2=00;
sec1=00;        sec2=00;       esec1=00;           esec2=00;
```

Then I try to loop through this such that I can append the run number to the base variable name which is the only thing that stays the same (eg appending 1,2,3..etc to yr and then calling the $yr1 $yr2 $yr3 ... etc variables as defined above)

```
for count in `seq 1 $nruns`
do
    #start vars
    #**********
    ystart=$((yr$count))  
    mostart=$((mo$count)) 
    daystart=$((day$count))
    hrst=$((hr$count)) # but this removes my preceding 0 which I need. i.e, 
                       # here I get 0 instead of 00
    minst=$((min$count))
    secst=$((sec$count))

    # Similarly, for end time variables
    #end vars
    #**********
    yend=$((eyr$count))
    moend=$((emo$count))
    dayend=$((eday$count))
    hrend=$((ehr$count))
    minend=$((emin$count))
    secend=$((esec$count))
```

Now I try to make strings that I am using to substitute into a program file, but because of the above issues I get the following:

```
    sd1=$ystart-$mostart-$daystart\_$hrst:$minst:$secst
 #which gives me 2008-11-30_18:0:0 instead of 2008-11-30_18:00:00

    ed1=$yend-$moend-$dayend\_$hrend:$minend:$secend
 #which gives me 2008-12-2_0:0:0 instead of 2008-12-02_00:00:00
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you're asking about a different problem than the one you're having...

To start with a very literal answer: If you want to access a variable whose name is in another variable, you can use "indirect expansion" – the `${!...}` operator. For example:

```
var=yr$i; ystart=${!var}
var=mo$i; mostart=${!var}
...
```

However, what you're doing by appending an index number to variable names, is just inefficiently emulating an [array variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_type), even though bash *already has* arrays as a built-in data type:

```
yr=()   # declare `yr` to be an empty array
mo=()

yr[1]=2008
mo[1]=11

yr[2]=2009
mo[2]=01

for (( i=1; i <= nruns; i++ )); do

    echo "Date: ${yr[i]}-${mo[i]}-${day[i]}"

done
```

(You can also iterate over all 'keys' using `for i in ${!yr[@]}`.)

Finally, just to answer the last example: If you want to zero-pad numbers, you can use the `printf` command with format strings similar to those in C:

```
yr=2009
mo=4
day=7
hr=11
min=5

printf "%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d\n" $yr $mo $day $hr $min
# -> 2009-04-07 11:05
```

Here `%d` means a decimal number (the distinction between `%d` and `%s` is important in C but they're almost interchangeable in bash). `%2d` will make it at least 2 characters long and right-aligned (use negative width to left-align); `%02d` makes it zero-padded rather than space-padded.

```
printf "[%d] [%-4d] [%03d]\n" 1 2 3      # -> [1] [2   ] [003]
```